# How can I remove bubbles in a newly laid linoleum floor?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

We laid linoleum using glue but did not use a roller. It is bubbled all over. Can a roller be used after 8 hours and glue has dried? Will bubbles stay??

Comment: Yes, bubbles will stay....it is a poor craftsmanship

Answer (score 1):

You can try poking a pinhole thru the linoleum and hope to vent it that way... If you'd gotten to this before adhesive had set the roller might have been able to work the bubbles out to the edge. Best, of course, is to eliminate them as the lino is being put down.

Answer (score 1):

Try a blow dryer or heat gun (on low setting). Heat may soften the flooring (and maybe the glue) enough to then use a roller to eliminate bubbles. Be **very** careful not to get it too hot as the flooring will be permanently damaged. Start in an inconspicuous area to get a feel for the heat necessary then work from the middle toward the edges. It's worth a try before you pull up the entire floor, I have had some luck with this technique in the past, good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Many times the bubbles will go away on their own in a short time. They can be from gas from the glue